# add custom controls to respond with the active state of video.js controls

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I am using **video.js** to play my *.hls files and I am using their default skins. I added an exit control for the video using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I want that the exit controls disappear with the controls of the video while the user is inactive. HOW DO I DO IT? do I add some class at the element or do I add some code at the js?[showing the default video controls from video.js and I add an exit control at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAJk1.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

From my understanding, using "useractive" and "userinactive" event to show or hide your css class would be the best way without manipulating the video.js code itself..

If you want to manipulate the code itself then you can look for the player.controlBar.fadeIn() and player.controlBar.fadeOut() function (assuming player is the video object..) and add your css class into the functions.

[The Doc for Video.js](https://tradecaptain.com/Component/website/campaigns/walid/video.js/docs/api/tutorial-options.html) has some information about the events I've mentioned.
This should help.